# Ember.js unclear error message: "TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property '__ember1346625712617'"

Tags: ember.js

I suspect that this problem might be connected to my routing, or my view. Here are both:

```
App.router = Ember.Router.create({
    enableLogging: true,
    location: 'history',
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/admin/',
            redirectsTo: 'login'
        }),
        login: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/admin/login/',
            doLogin: function(router, context) {
                "use strict";
                router.transitionTo('dashboard', context);
            },
            connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                "use strict";
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('login', "login");
            }
        }),
        dashboard: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/admin/dashboard/',
            doLogout: function(router, context) {
                "use strict";
                router.transitionTo('login', context);
            },
            connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                "use strict";
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('sidebar', 'sidebar');
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('toolbar', 'toolbar');
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('dashboard', 'dashboard');
            }
        }),
        articles: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/admin/articles/',
            connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                "use strict";
                console.log("here");
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('sidebar', 'sidebar');
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('toolbar', 'toolbar');
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('articles', 'articles');
            }
        })
    })
});
```

And my view in question:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sidebar">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://boxed.hu/static/boxed.hu/images/sitebuild/logo.png">
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="dashboardMenu" href="" data-module="dashboard" class="selected" {{action dashboard}}>
                Dashboard
                <span class="icon-home"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="articlesMenu" href="" data-module="articles" class="" {{action articles}}>
                Articles
                <span class="icon-copy"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="mediaMenu" href="" data-module="media" class="" {{action media}}>
                Media
                <span class="icon-picture"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="pagesMenu" href="" data-module="pages" class="" {{action pages}}>
                Pages
                <span class="icon-file"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="commentsMenu" href="" data-module="comments" class="" {{action comments}}>
                Comments
                <span class="icon-comments"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="usersMenu" href="" data-module="users" class="" {{action users}}>
                Users
                <span class="icon-user"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="rolesMenu" href="" data-module="roles" class="" {{action roles}}>
                Roles
                <span class="icon-unlock"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

When I click on one of the elements in the list, I get this console output:

```
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'articles' to state root.

TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property '__ember1346625712617'
[Break On This Error]   

o_defineProperty(this, GUID_KEY, undefinedDescriptor);
```

I was planning to debug the code, but I thought that a post here might bring quicker answers then my debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't specifically an Ember error, but a browser one: [Error in accessor property: can't redefine non-configurable property 'status'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924250/error-in-accessor-property-cant-redefine-non-configurable-property-status).

I suspect you're seeing it as result of naming an action (`{{action articles}}`) the same as a state.

Comment: I renamed the {{action articles}} to {{action articlesAction}} and it works like charm. This also helped a bit in understanding the secrets of the router. Thaks!