# Why can't I redefine a property in a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a object using `Object.create` and I want to add properties to it.

```
> var o = Object.create({});
undefined

> Object.defineProperty(o, "foo", {value: 43, enumerable: true});
{foo: 43}

> o
{foo: 43}

> o.foo
43

> for (var i in o) { console.log(i); }
foo

> Object.keys(o)
['foo']

> Object.defineProperty(o, "foo", {value: 43, enumerable: false });
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: bar
```

Q1) Why can't I redefine the property ?

```
> o.__proto__
{}

> o.prototype
undefined
```

Q2) Why is the prototype empty ? And why are these 2 values different i.e. `{}` vs `undefined` ?

Comment: Be careful with [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Answer (score 78):

You are unable to redefine the property because `Object.defineProperty()` defaults to non-configurable properties, from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> configurable
>
> true if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.
>       Defaults to false.

So this defaults to false - you'd need to pass it `configurable: true` to allow it.

Answer (score 58):

1. Properties defined through [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) are, by default, [non-`configurable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

   To allow them to be redefined, or reconfigured, they have to be defined with this attribute set to `true`.

   ```
   var o = Object.create({});

   Object.defineProperty(o, "foo", {
       value: 42,
       enumerable: true,
       configurable: true
   });

   console.log(o); // { foo: 42 }

   Object.defineProperty(o, "foo", {
       value: 45,
       enumerable: true,
       configurable: true
   });

   console.log(o); // { foo: 45 }
   ```

   ---
2. `o.prototype` is `undefined` because objects don't typically have `prototype` properties.

   Such properties are found on constructor `function`s for `new` instances to inherit from, roughly equivalent to:

   ```
   function Foo() {}

   //  ... = new Foo();
   var bar = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
   Foo.call(bar);
   ```

   Object are, however, aware of their prototype objects. They're referenced through an [internal `[[Prototype]]` property](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2), which `__proto__` is/was an unofficial getter/setter of:

   ```
   console.log(o.__proto__); // {}
   ```

   The standardized way to read the `[[Prototype]]` is with [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf):

   ```
   console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(o)); // {}
   ```

Comment: And ES6 may introduce [*Object.setPrototypeOf*](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.setprototypeof), overwhelmed by choice…

Answer (score 13):

Only when both **writable** and **configurable** are false, "Cannot redefine property" will happen.

If **writable** or **configurable** is true, the error will disappear.

```
"use strict"

var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "name",
{
   value: "Fundebug",
   writable: false,
   configurable: false
})

Object.defineProperty(obj, "name",
{
   value: "云麒"
}) // “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: name”
```

Therefore, jdphenix and Jonathan are not exactly correct.

Answer (score 5):

```
Object.defineProperty(o, "foo", {value: 43, enumerable: true});
```

This line defines property `foo` on object `o` with value:43 and attributes `enumerable:true`, `writable:false`, `configurable:false`. If the property exists, `defineProperty` updates its flags. Otherwise, it creates the property with the given value and flags; in that case, if a flag is not supplied, it is assumed **false**.

So, here we are making our property **non-configurable** as `configurable` flag (or attribute) is **false**.

> Making a property `non-configurable` is a one-way road. We cannot change
> it back with `defineProperty`.
>
> To be precise, non-configurability imposes several restrictions on
> defineProperty:

- Can’t change configurable flag.
- Can’t change enumerable flag.
- Can’t change writable: false to true (the other way round works).
- Can’t change get/set for an accessor property (but can assign them if absent).

So be careful with `configurable` flag in `defineProperty`, always set it to true in defineProperty if you want to change *enumerable* and *writable* attributes(or flag). **Once you set configurable false you cant set it to true.**

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason of this could be your version problem.
**Node 10 doesn't allow live binding** but the newer versions now allow this.
Please check you are on node 12 or plus.