# Obj.defineProperty TypeError: : can't redefine non-configurable property 'x_origen'

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to increase a property by adding aumento to it and because of that I'm using obj.defineProperty. However I'm getting the error:
 TypeError: : can't redefine non-configurable property 'x_origen'
How can I solve that?

```
var aument = 0;
            function aumento(){ 
            aument += 2.5;
            }
            setInterval(aumento, 20)

        function crear_clase_ladrillo (x_origen_in, y_origen_in, x_final_in, y_final_in, mi_estado, mi_velocidad, mi_id){

            this.nueva_x_origen = this.x_origen + this.velocidad;
            this.y_origen = y_origen_in;
            this.x_final = x_final_in;
            this.nueva_x_final = this.x_final + this.velocidad;
            this.y_final = y_final_in;         
            this.estado      = mi_estado;
            this.velocidad   = mi_velocidad;
            this.id_elemento = mi_id;
            Object.defineProperty(this, 'x_origen', {
                get: function () { return x_origen_in + aument; }
              });

            this.DESPLAZAR_LADRILLO  = desplazar_ladrillo;
            this.F0         = f0;
            this.F2         = f2;
            this.crear_ladrillo = crear_ladrillo;
            this.obtener_x_origen_ladrillo = obtener_x_origen_ladrillo;
            this.obtener_y_origen_ladrillo = obtener_y_origen_ladrillo;
            this.obtener_x_final_ladrillo = obtener_x_final_ladrillo;
            this.obtener_y_final_ladrillo = obtener_y_final_ladrillo;

        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I redefine a property in a Javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517989/why-cant-i-redefine-a-property-in-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

`Object.defineProperty()` has several default values, which are all false. You need to explicitly make it a configurable value:

```
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'x_origen', {
            get: function () { return x_origen_in + aument; },
            configurable: true
            enumerable: true
          });
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description for more information.