# Frogger JavaScript game - Redefine Object Property

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to write a frogger game like in OOP javascript. I have a couple of sprites for the player to choose from. What I want to achieve is that when the user selects the specific sprite, it updates the correct one when instantiating the player object.
I get an error when I try to redefine the property. I have tried a couple of solutions but with no success. **What am i doing wrong? please help!**

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First Attempt: Frogger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dd.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>         
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-2 characters" style="border:1px solid black">
                <img src="images/char-boy.png" alt="char-boy"><input type="radio" name="sprite" value="images/char-boy.png" checked="checked"> 
                <img src="images/char-cat-girl.png" alt="char-boy"><input type="radio" name="sprite" value="images/char-cat-girl.png"> 
                <img src="images/char-horn-girl.png" alt="char-boy"><input type="radio" name="sprite" value="images/char-horn-girl.png"> 
                <img src="images/char-pink-girl.png" alt="char-boy"><input type="radio" name="sprite" value="images/char-pink-girl.png"> 
                <img src="images/char-princess-girl.png" alt="char-boy"><input type="radio" name="sprite" value="images/char-princess-girl.png">  
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="game"></div>
        </div>        
    </div>

    <script src="js/resources.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/engine.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var Player = function(){    
    //What sprite to use    
    this.sprite = $("input[name='sprite']:checked").val();          
    //initial x location
    this.x = 200;
    //initial y location
    this.y = 400;
};

$(document).on("click", 'input:radio[name="sprite"]',
function(){            
    var result = $("input[name='sprite']:checked").val();
    console.log(result);
    Object.defineProperty(Player.prototype, 'sprite', {
        get: function(){
            return this.sprite;
        },
        set: function(result){
            this.sprite = result;
        }
    });           
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because by default you can't redefine properties in JavaScript. [See this answer for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517989/why-cant-i-redefine-a-property-in-a-javascript-object#25518028) If you want to define properties on an object, it should be one in the player constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `Player` constructor in a closure to pass in the sprite before instantiation:

```js
var PlayerWithSprite = function (sprite) {    

    return function () {
        //What sprite to use    
        this.sprite = sprite;
        //initial x location
        this.x = 200;
        //initial y location
        this.y = 400;
    };
    
};

var Player = PlayerWithSprite('my-sprite');

var playerInstance = new Player();

console.log(playerInstance);
```

Comment: The problem is i need a default value for sprite otherwise when I try to draw the sprite image later on in the code i get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Player class to get you started:

```
class Player
{
  constructor(x,y)
  {
    var player = this;    

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.sprite = null;

    $('input:radio[name="sprite"]').click(function(){
      player.sprite = $("input[name='sprite']:checked").val();
    });
   }
}

$(function(){
  new Player(200,400);
});
```

Comment: The problem is i need a default value for sprite otherwise when I try to draw the sprite image later on in the code i get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement ..."