# Error "Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'location'" on window.location in javascript using in Universal Windows app (UAP/UWP)

Tags: javascript, windows, browser, uwp, window.location

I had a Windows 8.1 jsproject, now updated to the Universal Windows (UAP/UWP)app.

Previously this function was working, it was calling like

```
installLocationProxy(window);
installLocationProxy(document);

function installLocationProxy(obj) {
            var descriptor;
            var descriptorProto = obj;
            do {
                descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(descriptorProto, "location");
                descriptorProto = !descriptor && descriptorProto && Object.getPrototypeOf(descriptorProto);
            } while (descriptor == null);
            if (!descriptor || !descriptor.get || !descriptor.set)
                return;
            var proxy = new LocationProxy(descriptor.get.call(obj));
            Object.defineProperty(obj, "location", {
                "get": function () {
                    return proxy;
                },
                "set": function (location) {
                    if (typeof location === 'string' || location && location instanceof String) {
                        proxy.assign(location, NavigationMethods.Location);
                    }
                    else {
                        return descriptor.set.call(obj, location);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

but now I am getting error "Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'location'" on this line `Object.defineProperty(obj, "location"`.

While googling I found that the now the window.location is readonly and not writable, so cannot be overridden.

For reference it can be checked here
https://gist.github.com/zacharytamas/082e538784ebe07e40f9

But I am not sure how to override the `window.location` property? Can anybody help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I redefine a property in a Javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517989/why-cant-i-redefine-a-property-in-a-javascript-object)