# jest spyOn not working on index file, cannot redefine property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, spyon

I have `UserContext` and a hook `useUser` exported from `src/app/context/user-context.tsx`.
Additionally I have an index.tsx file in `src/app/context` which exports all child modules.

If I spyOn `src/app/context/user-context` it works but changing the import to `src/app/context` I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useUser at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
```

Why is that?

Source code:

```js
// src/app/context/user-context.tsx

export const UserContext = React.createContext({});

export function useUser() {
  return useContext(UserContext);;
}
```

```js
// src/app/context/index.tsx

export * from "./user-context";
```

```js
// *.spec.tsx

// This works:
import * as UserContext from "src/app/context/user-context";

// This does not work:
// import * as UserContext from "src/app/context";

it("should render complete navigation when user is logged in", () => {

    jest.spyOn(UserContext, "useUser").mockReturnValue({
        user: mockUser,
        update: (user) => null,
        initialized: true,
    });
})
```

Comment: How are you importing `UserContext` in the code being tested? If you're importing from "src/app/context/user-context", then you'll need to import it the same way in the spec file, or else it won't be mocking the same thing.

Though your TypeError seems like a different issue...

Comment: I think you need to read this article: https://www.chakshunyu.com/blog/how-to-mock-only-one-function-from-a-module-in-jest/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you take a look at the js code [produced](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=ie%2010&build=&builtIns=usage&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAKjgMyhAtnARAOgPQCuAzsFALQDGEAdjKDFgNxA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.16.3&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D) for a re-export it looks like this

```js
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _context = require("context");

Object.keys(_context).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === "default" || key === "__esModule") return;
  if (key in exports && exports[key] === _context[key]) return;
  Object.defineProperty(exports, key, {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function get() {
      return _context[key];
    }
  });
});
```

and the error you get is due to the compiler not adding `configurable: true` in the options for `defineProperty`, which would allow jest to redefine the export to mock it, from [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

> configurable
>
> **true** if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the
> property may be deleted from the corresponding object. **Defaults to `false`**.

I think you could tweak your config somehow to make the compiler add that, but it all depends on the tooling you're using.

A more accessible approach would be using `jest.mock` instead of `jest.spyOn` to mock the user-context file rather than trying to redefine an unconfigurable export

```js
it("should render complete navigation when user is logged in", () => {
  jest.mock('./user-context', () => {
    return {
      ...jest.requireActual('./user-context'),
      useUser: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        user: {},
        update: (user: any) => null,
        initialized: true
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: If the lack of "configurable" is the case, won't babel's config assumption "constantReexports" fix that? [Check here](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=ie%2010&build=&builtIns=usage&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAKjgMyhAtnARAOgPQCuAzsFALQDGEAdjKDFgNxA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.16.3&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%22constantReexports%22%3Atrue%7D). But doesn't work for me tbh

Comment: @eXception Thanks for the hint. [Enabling the `constantReexports` assumption](https://github.com/Xunnamius/unified-utils/blob/main/babel.config.js) fixed it for me in my Jest tests :)

Answer (score 103):

Can't agree that using `jest.mock()` instead of `spyOn()` is a good solution. With that approach you have to mock **all** functions once at the top of your spec file.

But some of the test cases might need a different setup or stay real.

Anyway, I want to continue use `spyOn()`.

A better way is to add following lines at the top of your spec file (right after the imports and before `describe()`).

```
import * as Foo from 'path/to/file'; 

jest.mock('path/to/file', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,    //    <----- this __esModule: true is important
    ...jest.requireActual('path/to/file')
  };
});

...

//just do a normal spyOn() as you did before somewhere in your test:
jest.spyOn(Foo, 'fn');
```

P.S. Also could be an one-liner:

```
jest.mock('path/to/file', () => ({ __esModule: true, ...jest.requireActual('path/to/file') }));
```

P.P.S. Put `'path/to/file'` to a constant might not work. At least for me it didn't. So sadly you need to repeat the actual path 3 times.

Comment: spying on a mock really defeats the purpose of spying at all. not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: @PouyaAtaei you are not spying on mock, since you are doing `jest.requireActual`. I also not happy with this solution, but can't find anything better. Probably a better solution would be to adjust the way babel compiles files for unit tests (with `configurable: true`), but for that you need to create a babel plugin I guess

Comment: excellent find, works for me mocking `useBreakpointValue` from `@chakra-ui/media-query` - thanks!

Comment: A clarification: The reason you can't use a constant is that the mock statement is hoisted, meaning that it is always moved to the top of the file by jest.

Answer (score 4):

The `UserContext` when re-exported from `app/context/index.tsx` throws that issue since it's a bug with Typescript on how it handled re-exports in versions prior to 3.9.

This issue was fixed as of version 3.9, so upgrade Typescript in your project to this version or later ones.

> This issue was [reported here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38530) and resolved
> with comments on the [fix here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38809)

below is a workaround without version upgrades.

Have an object in your `index.tsx` file with properties as the imported methods and then export the object.

inside `src/app/context/index.tsx`

```
import { useUser } from './context/user-context.tsx'

const context = {
  useUser,
  otherFunctionsIfAny
}

export default context;
```

or this should also work,

```
import * as useUser from './context/user-context.tsx';

export { useUser };

export default useUser;
```

Then spy on them,

```
import * as UserContext from "src/app/context";

it("should render complete navigation when user is logged in", () => {

    jest.spyOn(UserContext, "useUser").mockReturnValue({
        user: mockUser,
        update: (user) => null,
        initialized: true,
    });
});
```

[Ref](https://github.com/aelbore/esbuild-jest/issues/26#issuecomment-893763840)

**Good to Know**:- Besides the issue with re-exports, the previous versions did not support live bindings as well i.e., when the exporting module changes, importing modules were not able to see changes happened on the exporter side.

Ex:

Test.js

```
let num = 10;

function add() {
    ++num;  // Value is mutated
}

exports.num = num;
exports.add = add;
```

index.js

[image]

A [similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43081) but due to the import's path.

The reason for this error message (JavaScript) is explained in this post [TypeError: Cannot redefine property:  Function.defineProperty ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517989/why-cant-i-redefine-a-property-in-a-javascript-object)

Comment: We're using TS 4.4.4, but still has the issue; I believe it's the issue of `esbuild`?

Comment: Workaround if you are using ESbuild: https://github.com/aelbore/esbuild-jest/issues/26

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was that i tried to redefine `index.tsx` located in parential `useSteps` folder with the same name as hook file:

my folder structure was like:

```
hooks/useSteps/
              index.tsx
              useSteps/useSteps.tsx
```

It was like this
`import * as step from './hooks/useSteps';`

but should be like this
`import * as step from './hooks/useSteps/useSteps';`

Answer (score 2):

I vote for @diedu's reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69951703/13605919.
I have also faced this same problem in one of my test cases and i fixed it by simply adding

> jest.mock("path to the file");

Eg:

```
import * as Obj from "path to the file";
jest.mock("path to the file");
const spy = jest.spyOn(Obj, "prop")
spy.mockImplementation(() => {
 // Desired mock Implementation 
}
```

**Explanation on spying without mocking:**

- When you do an import without mocking that importing file path, it actually downloads / importing the entire file and its inner and nested inner imports as well.
- And when you do a spyOn one of its property and mocking
  implementation for that spied property, it actually mock only that
  particular property of the file.
- So this doesn't work for re-exported constants.
- The reason behind it is, the entire file is imported as an object without having configurable as true

**Explanation on mocking before spying:**

- when you add jest.mock("path to the file") just before Spying, it is not actually importing the file.
- So there is no descriptor associated with the object and you are the
  one who is gonna add descriptors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another, generic alternative to the solutions mentioned above would be to wrap `Object.defineProperty()` to ensure that the exported objects are configurable:

```
// The following Object.defineProperty wrapper will ensure that all esModule exports
// are configurable and can be mocked by Jest.
const objectDefineProperty = Object.defineProperty;
Object.defineProperty = function <T>(obj: T, propertyName: PropertyKey, attributes: PropertyDescriptor & ThisType<any>): T {
  if ((obj as { __esModule?: true })['__esModule']) {
    attributes = { ...attributes, configurable: true };
  }
  return objectDefineProperty(obj, propertyName, attributes);
};
```

This code should then be executed as (or within) the first script provided via the [setupFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) Jest config option.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `replaceProperty` method instead.

Documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestreplacepropertyobject-propertykey-value

```
import * as UserContext from "src/app/context";

it('should render complete navigation when user is logged in', () => {
    jest.replaceProperty(UserContext, 'useUser', {
        user: mockUser,
        update: (user) => null,
        initialized: true,
    });
})
```