# jest spyOn not working, TypeError: Cannot redefine property:XXX at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, pnpm

Recently, I have used `pnpm` instead of `npm` in the program. When I use the script `pnpm test`, unit test throw errors which don't happen when I use `npm test`. All error codes like follow codes

```
import * as Test from '@/testfile/test'

describe('some ut', () => {
  test('test', () => {
     jest
      .spyOn(Test, 'someTest')
      .mockReturnValue({ returnValue: true });
  })
```

and all errors like this

```
TypeError: Cannot redefine property:'someTest'
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
```

And I tried some solutions and workaround but these solutions don't work.

**Solution 1:**

```
import { someTest } from '@/testfile/test'

describe('some ut', () => {
  test('test', () => {
     const Test = { someTest }
     jest
      .spyOn(Test, 'someTest')
      .mockReturnValue({ returnValue: true });
  })
```

**Solution 2:**

```
describe('some ut', () => {
  test('test', () => {
     jest.mock('@/testfile/test', () => {
       someTest: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ returnValue: true })
     })
  })
```

**Solution 3**:
[jest spyOn not working on index file, cannot redefine property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67872622/jest-spyon-not-working-on-index-file-cannot-redefine-property/69951703#69951703)

And I don't know what difference between `npm` and `pnpm`.

Comment: in Solution 2 you are missing a t in the file name `'@/testfile/tes',`. In any case, how does the file you are trying to mock look like. can you edit the message to show us how this `someTest` looks like?

Comment: sorry for the typo. `someTest` is a common function. There are so many different functions like `someTest` in the project. Some are a util function, some return a promise, and some return another callback function. Thanks. I tried to mock the function but failed

Comment: Mocking in Jest is a mess, I had so many issues with it over the years. Maybe this can help: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestcreatemockfrommodulemodulename

Comment: Thx. I'll check this doc~

Answer (score 0):

compare the previous version and find out the lib version(@jest/console, @jest/core, @jest/environment, etc.) in `node_modules` has been changed. My `jest` version is 28.1.1. These lib's versions are 28.1.3. So I downgraded these versions and fixed the issue.